# How to run PyMC in 'base' environment?

Tags: python, import, module, environment, pymc

When I run Python in the `base` environment and then call `import pymc` I run into the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc.Container_values'

How can I solve this problem?

Installing PyMC requires the creation of a new environment. When running Python in this new environment and calling `import pymc` everything works fine. Then I added the path of the module `pymc` to `sys.path` with the intention to use it in the `base` environment. I am using Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use PyMC in the base environment, then you can run `pip install pymc` (or more likely `conda -c conda-forge install "pymc>=4"`) in the base environment. It's not generally recommended to do that, but it's not disallowed either, if you have good reasons to need it in the base environment.

The reason it's not recommended to do that is that it will probably install a bunch of dependencies, which might conflict with other packages you'll need for other projects. But again, doing it in an environment is not a hard requirement, just a strong recommendation.

PS: I took my conda version by adapting the instructions at https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/latest/installation.html